# Scala :: Unable to get the output in command prompt

Tags: scala, scala-collections

```html
object ScalaTest{
    def main (args: Array[String]){
        var i =0

        while(i<=10){
            println(i)
            i +=1
        }
    }
}
```

When i do

```
c:\ Scalac ScalaTest.scala \\ it goes to the next line but
c:\ Scala ScalaTest.scala \\ Nothing is happening cursor is blinking in the next line but no response.
```

What am i doing wrong here. Not able to see the output or anything.
Please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The file you should execute with the `scala` command after compiling is not the source file but the resulting binary file from `scalac`.

If you take a look at: http://www.scala-lang.org/old/node/166

You should then try:

```
  scalac ScalaTest.scala

  scala ScalaTest
```

---

I tried your code in the REPL console and it's working ok.
However, it might not be the most idiomatic Scala code ever.

It's a good approach to take a look at `Range` and trying something like:

```
  (0 to 10).foreach(println)
```

Which produce the same result without a mutable variable

Comment: Hi Aurelien,
Thank you very Much Actually "scala ScalaTest" Worked. 
But for the "Scala ScalaTest.scala"
the console waited for about 45 mins then it gave be the below 
Error: "There is insufficient memory for the Java Runtime Environment to continue.Native memory allocation(malloc) failed to allocate 1048576 bytes for AllocateHeap.. Could not connect to compilation daemon after 300 attempts" .- I think .. may be due to no Ram Memory allocation.